# how can i get push notification using C2DM in titanium android?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, titanium-mobile

I i am developing an android application using [appcelerator titanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appcelerator_Titanium). We can get push notification in native application in android using C2Dm. But i did not get a way to get push notification in titanium. Please provide me sample source code to get push notification in android using [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C2DM by adding java C2DM module. Get the GitHub code from [here](https://github.com/IGx89/titanium-c2dm).

I have not tried this, by this is mention in [Titanium website forum](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/136737/c2dm-for-android).

This [discussion](http://search.appcelerator.com/?q=c2dm&x=0&y=0) may also useful for use.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not getting imported this project into my titanium framework. How can i import and compile and get result. Please provide me any steps explanation about this project. And suggest me is there any other ways to get push notifications like Urban Airship. thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not tried this myself...But I guess related project is Ant build.

Comment: Ok. Can we use this ant build in our project to get push notifications

Comment: maybe..if you are still unable to build project then create new project and copy all files into them.

Comment: I am not getting what is the modules and ant tools in that git hub application. I tried to impost it from git hub and failed to run. And i created separate  project any tried to execute but did not get success.